# jmp $ in NASM bootloader

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, bios, x86-16

I was trying to write the bootloader from [Bootloader](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html). The code written is

```
BITS 16

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax


    mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

    jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!


    text_string db 'This is my cool new OS!', 0


print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 0Eh     ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:
    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret


    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

What I couldn't understand is why are we writing jmp$. By writing jmp$ it enters an infinite loop. So, after entering an infinite loop, the last two lines

```
times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

are never executed.

Moreover why are we adding 288 to ax?

Comment: Well it doesn't have anything to do after printing, so infinite loop is the best it can do to avoid executing your text string and anything after it.

Comment: Adding 288 to 0x7c0 and storing it in the stack segment simply puts space between the stack and the bootloader. The memory area in between could be used as disk buffer etc.

Comment: One other variation of `jmp $` that you may also come across is the sequence `cli` `endloop: hlt` `jmp endloop`.

Answer (score 5):

`$` is the address of the current instruction, so `jmp $` is looping to itself. This is usually done for a fatal error.

Here, the loader is incomplete, so it's outputting a message and then looping. The "loop" instruction [hopefully] would be replaced by real code [to be added].

Things defined with the `db` or `dw` pseudo-ops are definitions for *data* and are *not* executable instructions [usually--unless you need a special instruction not known to the assembler].

So, without the infinite loop, you'd try to execute the data at `text_string:`, which would produce undefined/unexpected results, let alone trying to execute the last part of the boot block.

---

The `288` offset ...

The boot is loaded at address `0x07C00`. It is trying to set up its stack segment at location `(0x07C00 + 4096 + 512)` --> `0x8E00`. But, it's trying to put this into a segment register, so the value must be shifted right by 4 bits. `0x07C0` is *already* shifted and `288` is `(4096 + 512) >> 4` or `0x0120`. The final value for `SS` is `0x07C0 + 0x0120` --> `0x08E0` [at address `0x8E00`]

This seems wrong (i.e. the arithmetic doesn't match), but the `sp` register is set to `4096`, so the final resting place for `ss:sp` is address `0x9E00`.

In 8086 real mode addressing, all addresses use a segment register and some offset. The final address is: `address = (segreg << 4) + offset`. This gets done by the hardware on each instruction that accesses memory in some way.

When you jump around in code, you use the `CS` [code segment] register. Data access uses the `DS` [data segment] register. And stack access (e.g. `push/pop` or `%sp` relative, use the `SS` [stack segment] register. There is also an `ES` [extra segment] register that is used in string instructions.

Comment: The results are defined, just may be unexpected.

Comment: That means that the last two lines would never be executed?

Comment: @RichaTibrewal Right. Nor would you want them to be as they are _not_ instructions. Doing `dw` is like doing `unsigned short xx = 0xAA55;` in C. You wouldn't try to execute that (in C) would you?

Comment: Can you also explain the first six lines of the code?

Comment: @Ruslan, I would say after the signature is executed it would be undefined because you can't assume that the bytes in memory beyond that would be something known like 0x00.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Every time I did an edit [afterwards], I realized the math was wrong. I did it by hand, then kcalc, and finally perl. I was almost going to add a disclaimer: "hex math not accurate and I'm tired" :-)

Comment: No problem. I edited it with the proper calc. I'd like to make the observation that this code comes from MikeOS and in another SO question it was asked what sits between 0x7E00 and 0x8E00 (0x8e00 being lower extent of stack area). As I recall when I reviewed the MikeOS code they used that space beneath the stack and above the bootloader as a disk buffer area.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I wouldn't be surprised about the layout. In terms of that, it's like a heap area [but no allocations]. I did code a few years back that had to fit in 128KB [in a microblaze] and I used a similar layout. OP's code couldn't be the whole boot, so, curiously, what strategy does the MikeOS [any relation? :-)] use for multistage (ala grub)?

Comment: [MikeOS](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/) as far as I remember (it is a toyOS) doesn't use Multiboot spec, and part of the tutorial is doing the first stage manually.

Answer (score 0):

The last two statements are not executables statements, they are kind of pseudo-instructions or assembler directives. Here, they are used to assemble the object code and not some executable instructions, and to make sure that boot sector is of 512 bytes.

`jmp $` is however an executable instruction, and will be run after the loader has loaded it. While the last two lines are used (and not executed) by the assembler when it assembles the assembly code into an object file.